# Shared element is visible both in calling and called activity

Tags: android, android-transitions

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7p97RiAOcwucXZITG44ZFhVT2s/view?usp=sharing)'s a screencast from George Mount's [transition demo](https://halfthought.wordpress.com/2014/12/08/what-are-all-these-dang-transitions/) app.
You can see that the shadow around the hero element is darker for a moment. This is because both the calling and the called activity displayed the text for a short duration.

I would like to know if there is a workaround for this.

Comment: Your link is not accessible. Secondly you should always elaborate in your question, what is your code with snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to avoid the doubling of the shadow at the moment. There is no interlock with the shared element, so it is briefly drawn on both surfaces, and translucent elements (shadows included) are seen twice.

One way to ensure you don't see this is to drop the view (elevation -> 0) as a shared element exit transition, and then raise the view again as part of a shared element enter transition. The shadow will animate out and then animate back in again, but you won't see the double shadow.